# How to send few chars to shell buffer automatically/periodically

Tags: shell, ssh

I would like Emacs to send a few chars (command, ideally) to a specific buffer (ssh shell) so that the session does not terminate. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're probably better off setting `ServeAliveInterval` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive

Answer (score 2):

As [npostavs suggests](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38646/how-to-type-few-chars-to-shell-buffer-automatically-periodically#comment60960_38646), it is usually in your interest to use shell- or program-specific settings/functionality for this sort of task.

Nevertheless, the following is a simple PoC using timers<sup>[1]</sup> for sending input to `comint`-based subshells like `shell`, as well as the `term` emulator<sup>[2]</sup>.

```el
(defun my-term-send-string (&optional buffer string)
  "Send STRING to a shell process associated with BUFFER.
By default, BUFFER is \"*terminal*\" and STRING is empty."
  (let ((process (get-buffer-process (or buffer "*terminal*"))))
    (when (process-live-p process)
      (with-current-buffer (process-buffer process)
        (let ((input (or string "")))
          (cond ((derived-mode-p 'comint-mode)
                 (insert input)
                 (comint-send-input))
                ((derived-mode-p 'term-mode)
                 (term-send-string process input)
                 (term-send-input))))))))

;; Send empty input to `*terminal*' every 30 seconds
(run-at-time t 30 #'my-term-send-string)

;; Send ":" null command to `*shell*' every minute
(run-at-time t 60 #'my-term-send-string "*shell*" ":")
```

[1]: [`(elisp) Timers`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html).

[2]: [`(emacs) Shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html).